# Nested syntax folding

Tags: syntax-highlighting, folding

Assume I have a syntax as exemplified below and that I want to create a syntax folding definition for the nested `begin..end` pairs.

```
begin : label
  a = 0;
  begin
    b = 1;
  end
  c = 2;
  begin
    d = 3;
  end
end

if (a) begin
  w = 0;
end else begin
  if (b) begin
    y = 0;
  end else if (c) begin : another_label
    y = 1;
  end else begin
    y = 2;
  end
end
```

At the moment I have the following syntax defined, which has the obvious issue with the highlight of the `end` keyword and it also folds one line less when `end` is at column 1.

```
syn region blockContainer
    \ start="\<begin\>"
    \ end="\<end\>"
    \ skip="/[*/].*"
    \ transparent
    \ keepend extend
    \ containedin=ALLBUT,Comment
    \ contains=block
syn region block
    \ matchgroup=Statement
    \ start="\<begin\>"
    \ end="\<end\>"me=s-1
    \ transparent
    \ fold
    \ contained containedin=blockContainer
    \ contains=TOP
```

Ideally I would also like a second set of regions where folding only occurs for `begin..end` pairs where the `begin` has a label (`: something`).

I got to a point where I simply wasn't able to advance further with this syntax, so I started playing around with fold-expr. Unfortunately, the syntax is rather complex and the slowdown is quite noticeable when opening the files.

So, is any Vim syntax expert available to help me? :)